# Cocoa Pods error with pod install

Tags: ios, cocoapods

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Google/SignIn` required by `Podfile`
- `Google/SignIn` required by `Podfile`
- `Google/SignIn` required by `Podfile`
- `Google/SignIn` required by `Podfile`
- `Google/SignIn (= 1.3.2)` required by `Podfile.lock`

Specs satisfying the `Google/SignIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Specs satisfying the `Google/SignIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Specs satisfying the `Google/SignIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Specs satisfying the `Google/SignIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Specs satisfying the `Google/SignIn (= 1.3.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42164794/889289

Answer (score 67):

`Your deployment target has to be moved up to the highest minimum target required by any dependency.`
[image]
Also, make sure the global platform in your Podfile matches the highest minimum target required by any dependency.

Comment: how do you fine the minimum deployment target needed? I've looked around and can't find anything

Answer (score 7):

**Cocoapods error**

> dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

When
`.podfile`

```
platform :ios, '<version>'
```

is not equal to
`.podspec`

```
<variable>.platform = :ios, "<version>"
```

[[Local CocoaPod]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812997/4770877)

Comment: This is what I needed to find the minimum deployment target required by the offending plugin. The console output specifies the offending plugin (in OPs case, `Google/SignIn`) but does not specify the minimum deployment version number the plugin requires. Thanks!

Comment: In a Flutter iOS project, the required platform details can be found in the following location: `ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/<package_name>.json` which may include `"platforms": { "ios": "13.0" }` or similar in it.  Your project would need to target the maximum necessary among all your used packages.  This info is often also included in each package's release notes.

Comment: you literally save me!

Answer (score 4):

I went to my Podfile and changed my deployment target to the highest one that was in my Pods/Local Podspecs

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I selected my project at the top of my project navigator   -> General -> Deployment info -> Deployment Target -> (Set the the most current)﻿

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty self-explanatory. Your deployment target has to be moved up to the highest minimum target required by any dependency. Check what iOS version Google/SignIn requires. If this checks out, make sure all your deployment targets set a satisfactory minimum target version.

Comment: even after updating my podFile.lock , still got error this message : `Google/SignIn (= 2.4.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`

Comment: What is your minimum deployment target?

Comment: my minimum deployment target is 7.0 and here's my podFile

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'



target 'OACA' do
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4'
end

target 'OACATests' do

end

target 'OACAUITests' do

end

Comment: How can you find the minimum deployment target if the error message doesn't specify one?

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by removing my Google/SignIn version and installing again my pods.

Answer (score 1):

I solved via:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~4.0'
```

To

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, my minimum target is already high enough. I need a `pod update ThePackageName` (WARN: this will change the version you are using). See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4373 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google/SignIn SDK supports iOS7 or later. Try a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: i solved it by removing my Google/SignIn version and installing again my pods. thanks everyone .

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was

```
pod repo update
```

as the error details suggested