# How to use local-only project via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I am struggling to find a way to package an Xcode framework we created as a Pod that would only be used internally (not public, not on github).

How do I modify the `.podspec` to build the SDK from the local Xcode project on my development machine?

Comment: You can use `:path =>` for a local pod. But is your Pod in any Git repository (even if private)?

Comment: My idea is to have the Pod only locally so that I can use it only for debugging purposes and therefore not host it on any Git repository (neither private nor public). @Larme

Comment: In your podfile you can use as said `:path =>` to your local pod. I don't know how to bypass the source issue doing a `pod spec lint` though.

Comment: But how to create that local pod? All i have is the source for the pod so I would like to find a way to package that source code into a local pod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: you don't use the `.podspec` for this. Longer: the `.podfile` is mainly for specifying:

- external dependencies
- what to snarf out of the project, relative to the project folder

IIRC, other than some informational metadata, the `.podspec` does not address how you get to that project folder, as this is handled separately.

As mentioned in the comments, you *can* use the `Podfile` to use a local project, with the `:path =>` directive pointing to a local project folder. For example, you have the project in `/Users/me/proj` -- and the `.podspec` lives at the top-level -- your Podfile would have an entry like:

`pod 'MyPodName', :path => '/Users/me/proj'`

Warning: when you run `pod {update, install}`, this will pull whatever is checked out locally in that project at the time.

Answer (score 12):

**Local CocoaPods**

[[Dependency manager]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877)

[[Cocoapods with specyfic branch]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73836830/4770877)

Example with Git:
[image]

Textual

Podfile

```
//Podfile pod supports:
//default(try to find .podcpec in centralised repo), path
//-remote    
    pod 'PodName'
//-local     
    //local_path can be absolute or relative
    pod 'PodName', :path => '<local_path>.podspec'
```

Podspec

```
//Podspec source supports:
//git, svn, hg, http
//-remote    
    s.source = { :git => "https://url_to.git", :tag => "git_tag" }
//-local     
    s.source = { :git => 'file:///path_to_git_folder', :tag => "git_tag" }
    //or, where path_to_git_folder can be relative
    s.source = { :git => '/path_to_git_folder', :tag => "git_tag" }
```

Do not forget to commit your changes beforehand. `git_tag` can be the same as a branch name.

Several useful commands:

Update:

`Podfile`:

```
pod update
```

Check
`.podspec`:

```
pod spec lint "<some_path>.podspec" --quick
pod spec lint "<some_path>.podspec" --verbose --allow-warnings
```

Register session:

```
pod trunk register <email> '<name>' --description='<description>'
```

Release:

```
pod trunk push <file>.podspec --verbose --allow-warnings
```

Pod search[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218883/4770877):

```
pod search <pod_name>
```

[[Local Carthage]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397924/4770877)
[[Local Swift Package Manager]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66715856/4770877)

[[Android Maven local]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738150/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a private Git repository, add as a `source` to `Podfile`
Then deciding if the framework is going to be closed source or open source, then `podspec` file will be different.
all the `pod repo ...` will help you [Doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_repos)